# Ntp to sync only at specific time

Tags: linux, ntp

In a local network I have a local NTP server that uses stratum 2 to sync its time.

And there is a bunch of clients inside that local network who only see the local NTP server. Clients are continuously synced to the local NTP server.

Due to some specifics I'd like to avoid continuous syncing between my local NTP server and the external stratum 2 server.
Ideally, I'd like my local NTP server to sync only around 1 AM at night (I don't care if there's a significant jump during such a sync).

Is this possible to achieve with ntpd?

I tried experimenting with "server  127.127.1.0", minpoll setting and orphan mode but local clients refuse to accept NTP server if it's not truly in sync...

Comment: So let me understand the question - You want the machines to have the correct time only once a day? (well correct with each other)

Comment: This is correct. But throughout the day I want them to be continuously in sync with each other (so that all the machines have equally "wrong" time).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell ntp to sync like this: `sudo sntp -s pool.ntp.org`. Assuming "local ntp server" is called pool.ntp.org, this should work:

1. Open crontab with sudo so the syncing happens as root

   ```
   sudo crontab -e
   ```
2. Setup a cron job to do the syncing every day at 1am by adding the following line

   ```
   0 1 * * * sntp -s pool.ntp.org
   ```

Also, don't forget to stop ntpd if you don't want it to sync throughout the day.

Comment: This is not exacty what I was asking for. I do need to keep ntpd running to make sure the "wrong" time from my local NTP server is sent to all the local clients.